# Multiple column within row in bootstrap is not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my bootstrap HTML code snippet. It is working fine in all browsers except in `IE-11` . I am getting a horizontal scrollbar also the last 2 `div` `col-xs-6 inside a row` are coming in 2 different rows not in a single row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:aqua;">col-xs-12 inside a row</div>
      </div>
    </div>                      
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">   direct inside a row
      </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red;">col-xs-6 inside a row</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:orange;">col-xs-6 inside a row</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What version of bootstrap use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to specify the compatibility mode in the document header with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

Take a look to this link for more info:

[IE legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)